# Log4j, sequence of Java Parameters

Tags: java, java-7

```
java -Dlog4j.log.dir=C:/ttt/tttlog -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/ttt/printing/log4j.properties -jar C:/ttt/JavaPrinter.jar C:/ttt/tttdata/jasper/531110/tmp/1 2100000001.jrxml TB_21000.xml output.pdf n C:/xampp/htdocs/ttt/staticpublic/fonts
```

On a windows Server 2012 System, this command leads to a weird

```
Fehler: Hauptklasse .log.dir=C:.ttt.tttlog konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
```

(meaning: Mainclass not found or loaded)

It looks like java interprets the first parameter as if it would contain a class and not a parameter indicating a log directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work an another system? Did you try wrapping the parameters in quotes?

Comment: 1. yes, everywhere else it works. 2. yes, makes no difference

Comment: What happens if you swap the -D parameters?

Comment: It finally worked, when I put the parameters in quotes, the keys as well as the values

Comment: Yes that's what I suspected. It was probably the command line (PowerShell?) which interpreted the dots.